# Where am I wrong? ( Completely solved normal sum)

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, self-study, normal-distribution

A sample of 40 observations from a normal distribution X gave $Σx = 24$ and $Σx^2 = 596$. Performing a two-tailed test at the 5% level, test whether the mean of the distribution is zero.

What I did: Found the population variance: 596.42 (596 - [(24)^2)/40]*(40/39)

Used the $z$ statistic: $\frac{(0.6 - 0)}{(\frac{24.42}{6.324})}$ and got the value as 0.155

Answer is 0.983 
Where am I wrong?

Comment: Given that the average squared value of an observation is a mere $596/40\approx 15,$ is it really plausible that the variance will be $596.42$?  Since you don't show your work, how can we know where you went wrong?  Yes, you made a mistake somewhere.  Check the arithmetic.  If it's correct, then please *show us your steps.*  Please don't ask us to guess.

Comment: @whuber Sorry, have added my steps.

Answer (score 0):

How you can calculate **Population Variance**? and calculation is also wrong. $$s^2 = \frac{\sum x^2}{n}-Mean^2$$ $$=14.9-0.36$$ $$=14.54$$
Then accordingly $z$ will be changed.